# How do I fix the font problem as my first website ever created it's font doesn't match

Tags: html, fonts

I have just started learning web development,I have no knowledge about it but I'm very much interested in learning about web development,so I started with Dr Angela yu's web development course..and today for the first time I have created a cv/site and uploaded it but when I open the website from phone I see that the fonts are all messed up non of the fonts of the texts matches ..how do I fix it please help..I have just used HTML5 to build the site

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Show us your code. What does the HTML/CSS look like? What font do you expect to be picked? How does it render on your phone?  Try to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Generally speaking, please re-read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, https://sourav91-dot.github.io/cv/.  This is the http .. from pc everything looks good but when I open the same site with my phone browser the fonts looks messed up as in they differ from each other

Comment: Normally your question shouldn't depend on an external link, you should edit the code into the question itself. But looking at that site it looks like you don't specify any fonts (or any other type of styling) there at all. Why do you expect it to look a specific way?

Comment: Can you please tell me where and what changes should I do? So that the site looks proper.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "proper". It has the same look as all unstyled HTML has... which is bland but not terrible. If you want to apply styles then I suggest you **continue** with the course, and I'm sure it'll teach you some CSS basics as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your replies and the also for your time.